# Can I ask a question about how to disconnect someone from linkedin?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I think it will be "out of scope"... But I don't know where to ask this question on SE...

Comment: be sure to refer to http://stackexchange.com/sites

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Questions about how to use web applications can be asked on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), but they are not on-topic on Super User.